# Drupal Commerce or Ubercart to sell subscription for user (not for sell product)?

Tags: 7, commerce, notifications

I want to create a website like learning lessons, and user can watch this lessons when subscribe of this website .. like [lynda.com](http://lynda.com)

I studied [drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and [ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) modules, but I still confuse which one is the best for this type of sites.

help me please
thank you

Comment: I worked in a site where I  have subscription products, I used drupal commerce and commerce license, I had many difficulties but the site is working now.

Comment: I try to using drupal commerce on my site now, but it still not working good with me, and I see ubercart has a many services for subscription user, but when i ask they told me commerce is the best .. so I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a site like learning site. I think you can do this by using [Course](https://www.drupal.org/project/course) module.

> Create Drupal e-learning courses with any number of requirements for
>   completion.
>
> There's a slideshow from Drupaldelphia and a video as well.

Comment: thank you Nishant for this module .. it's look great .. and its support both commerce and ubercart .. but what you think the best to use with it?
and if i want to create another website like book reading online .. is there a module like Course?! and what the best for it, commerce or ubercart?

Comment: but i still don't know using commerce or ubercart, which one the best?

Comment: Refer to [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1433486) from here you will get the answer.